# Convert a non-standard format string to a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-formatting

In SQL Server, I queried a column called `DelDate` which contains all the date as character string like

```
"Thu 1/9/2022"
"Wed 12/9/2022"
```

It impossible to compare manipulate this column with other columns contain standard format dates. I tried to use the command like

```
Convert(DATE, DelDate)
```

but got the error message:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: You would need to strip the weekday out   ...  try_convert(date,substring('Thu 1/9/2022',4,10))

Comment: I assume you are showing us 2 values? As opposed to one value with 2 dates? Solution simple, just carry out some manual string manipulation to get it into a format that convert supports.

Comment: Is `1/9/2022` the 1st of September, or the 9th of January?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: The first time I tried @JohnCappelletti solution and failed because the data in the column is not in a consistent format.  Most of Weekday is represented using 3 letters, but I did notice several of them is presented like
"Thursday 20/10/2022". When striping out only first 3 strings it won't work for those special value. Is there a way to ignore those inconsistent format of weekday representations? Using code like this on rows with normal 3-letter weekday dates actually work.  
`Convert(Date,Substring(DelDate,4,11),103)as 'Delivery date',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(Date, RIGHT('Wed 12/9/2022', LEN('Wed 12/9/2022') - 4), 103) DelDate2
```

Comment: I need to elaborate about my question. DelDate column contains thousands of data like what I mentioned above, I want to convert them all. So, based on your answer, I tried    `Convert(DATE,Right(DelDate,LEN(DelDate)-4),103))` but still get the same error. Would you mind giving me some advice regrading this please?

Comment: I think there are other kinds of strings in that DelDate column. You may want to use Try_Convert instead of Convert only. If the cast does not succeed, Try_Convert will return NULL. Then you need to find out all the NULL rows and correct them.

Comment: @NeilW “This works great against the two values I showed you, but not against the thousands of rows in my table that I didn’t show you.” If you can’t fix the source of the data in the first place (these are awful ways to store dates), then at least narrow it down for people - show a value where it doesn’t work. We can’t tell what’s in your table and how many other formats there might be.

Comment: @Kuryuu Thanks. You are right, I noticed there are several dates were input in a trrrible way which caused the error. Sorry I didn't mention I am using Microsoft SQL 2019. Looks like "Try_convert" is not supported in SQL Management Studio

Comment: @kuryuu Problem solved, after set database compatibility level to 120 then use" try_convert" works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help.